# Magento2: How to get registered online customer only?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-session

**customer_list.phtml**

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $om->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Online\Grid\Collection');
$customerData = $customerSession->getData();
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($customerData);
exit;
```

**Result**

[image]

**Expected result**

I want to show registered online customer only.

Comment: In your collection, You can add filter like email id is not empty. so you will get only registered customer

Comment: in my case above code is returning only registered customer only!

Comment: Ok, Its all colection of customer like non resigtered and registered. @Pawan

Comment: But have one problem in collection. Suppose I  logout my account then user not removed from collection before 30 min. @Pawan

Comment: Yes it will keep for time which is defined in config

Comment: Any other solution there when i logout my account then user also sholud be not show in customer list. @Pawan

Comment: When I log out , above collection get empty..

Comment: Its working fine. Thanks! @Pawan

Comment: great, I added my comment as answer, so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your collection, You can add filter like `email id` Or `Customer Id` is not empty. 
So it will give you only registered customer.

When Customer log out , Collection will remove that customer.